# Weird geom_path behavior

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have noticed an odd behavior in `geom_path()` in `ggplot2`. I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or whether it's a bug.

Here's my data set:

```
x <- abs(rnorm(10))
y <- abs(rnorm(10)/10)
categs <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")

df <- data.frame(x,y,categs)
```

I make a plot with points and I join them using `geom_path`. Works well:

```
ggplot(df, aes(categs, x, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=x-y, ymax=x+y)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

However, if I reorder my levels, for instance like this:

```
df$categs <- factor(df$categs, levels = c("f","i","c","g","e","a","d","h","b","j"))
```

[image]

then `geom_plot` still keeps the original order (although the order of the factor levels has been updated on the x axis).

Any guesses at what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order the *df* rows based on *df$categs*, **geom_path** goes row-by-row to plot:

```
ggplot(df[ order(df$categs), ], aes(categs, x, group=1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=x-y, ymax=x+y)) + 
  geom_path()
```

From `?geom_path` manual:

> *geom_path()* connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data.